# Is there any need to update again on ios 7 when i have updated it one month ago using ios 7 beta version?

Tags: ios

I update my iphone 4 on ios 7 beta version one month ago. Is there any need to download ios 7 full version and update again? However in settings (software update tab) it is showed that your software is up to date.

Answer (score 2):

You should update your phone to the Gold Master (GM) or restore your phone back to iOS 6 and then update to iOS7 using the public version.

If you continue to use the beta, you will not have all the latest updates/fixes from GM and may also run into issues later.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should definitely update to the release version of iOS7. That said, when the first update comes out, be it 7.0.1 or 7.1, that update will replace the OS anyway, so maybe you could wait for that time.

Comment: Will that be true for the beta or just if you have the production version. GvM's answer suggests the former

Answer (score 0):

My iPad with iOS7 beta also reported it is up to date after release of final version. But when **connected it directly to iTunes via cable**,  I got it updated. Perhaps it is same with iPhone.